# Error in tests using mock: Wanted but not invoked:

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I try to write integration tests for my Spring boot controller. Here is my controller method which I want to test:

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getAllBooks(Model model, @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page, @RequestParam("size") Optional<Integer> size) {
        int currentPage = page.orElse(FIRST_PAGE);
        int pageSize = size.orElse(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);

        Page<Book> bookPage = bookService.getAllBooks(PageRequest.of(currentPage - 1, pageSize));
        Set<String> categories = bookService.findAllCategories();

        model.addAttribute("categories", categories);
        model.addAttribute("currentPage", currentPage);
        model.addAttribute("books", bookPage);

        int totalPages = bookPage.getTotalPages();
        if (totalPages > 0) {
            List<Integer> pageNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, totalPages)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            model.addAttribute("pageNumbers", pageNumbers);
        }

        return "library";
    }
```

And here is my class with tests:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class BookControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Mock
    BookService bookService;
    @Mock
    BookRepository bookRepository;

    private final String category = "forTest";

    final Book book = new Book("test1", 9999, "testAuthor1", 1, "test1");

    @BeforeEach
    public void initEach() {
        bookService.addNewBook(book, category, "not used");
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void deleteEach() {
        bookRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void getAllBooksTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")
                        .param("page", "1")
                        .param("size", "20"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        ArgumentCaptor<Pageable> pageableCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Pageable.class);

        verify(bookRepository).findAll(pageableCaptor.capture());
        PageRequest pageable = (PageRequest) pageableCaptor.getValue();

        assertThat(pageable).hasPageNumber(1);
        assertThat(pageable).hasPageSize(20);
    }
}
```

I wrote custom assertThat methods, which looks like:

```
class PageableAssert extends AbstractAssert<PageableAssert, Pageable> {

    PageableAssert(Pageable pageable) {
        super(pageable, PageableAssert.class);
    }

    static PageableAssert assertThat(Pageable actual) {
        return new PageableAssert(actual);
    }

    void hasPageSize(int expectedPageSize) {
        if (!Objects.equals(actual.getPageSize(), expectedPageSize)) {
            failWithMessage("expected page size to be <%s> but was <%s>", expectedPageSize, actual.getPageSize());
        }
    }

    void hasPageNumber(int expectedPageNumber) {
        if (!Objects.equals(actual.getPageNumber(), expectedPageNumber)) {
            failWithMessage("expected page number to be <%s> but was <%s>", expectedPageNumber, actual.getPageNumber());
        }
    }

    PageableAssert hasSort(String field, Sort.Direction direction) {

        Sort.Order actualOrder = actual.getSort().getOrderFor(field);

        if (actualOrder == null) {
            failWithMessage("expected sort for field <%s> to be <%s> but was null", field, direction);
        } else if (actualOrder.getDirection() != direction) {
            failWithMessage("expected sort for field <%s> to be <%s> but was <%s>", field, direction, actualOrder.getDirection());
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

But as I correctly understand my problem appears in this line:
`verify(bookRepository).findAll(pageableCaptor.capture());`
so my custom asserts cannot influence the occurrence of this error which looks like:
**Wanted but not invoked:
bookRepository.findAll();
-> at kpi.diploma.ovcharenko.controller.BookControllerTests.getAllBooksTest(BookControllerTests.java:58)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.**
Can you help me with this problem, because I totally don't know how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test, you're verifying that `bookRepository.findAll` was invoked, but in the method you're testing, bookRepository isn't even referenced.

What you want to verify is that `bookService.getAllBooks` and `bookService.findAllCategories` are being invoked.

If you want to verify that your bookRepository invocations are being called correctly, write a test around the bookService methods, as I assume this is where those calls are made.

Also, I should add that since your method under test uses a response from those mocks, you need to create a when()->then() statement to ensure that those calls return some data, otherwise you're going to get a null pointer exception when it reaches this line: `int totalPages = bookPage.getTotalPages();`

Something like,

```
Page<Book> bookPage =  Mockito.mock(Page.class);
when(bookService.getAllBooks(any()).thenReturn(bookPage);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped me! I just starting to study Mock, so thank you)